# The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int)

Tags: java, string

okay so I'm new to Java and I'm trying to make my first program and i get this message i cant seem to fix:

> `The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int).`

Here is the Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame{
    private JPanel GamePanel;
    private JLabel statusbar;

    public Gui(){
        super("Title");
        GamePanel = new JPanel();
        GamePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(GamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        statusbar = new JLabel("default");
        add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        GamePanel.addMouseListener(handler);
    }

    class HandlerClass implements MouseListener{
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
            //here is where the problem is!
            statusbar.setText(String.format("%d, %d", event.getX(), event.getY());
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            statusbar.setText("ok?");
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
            statusbar.setText("something");
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            statusbar.setText("something");
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            statusbar.setText("something");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error messages of this type indicate a difference between the types of parameters you're giving the method, and the types it expects.  In this case it is asking for a `String` and an Array of `Object`(Object[]) but you're giving it a String and two Integers.  You need to package these as an Array first.

```
int [] temp = {event.getX(), event.getY()};
statusbar.setText(String.format("%d, %d", temp);
```

Comment: I'm not particularly sure this will work (that should probably be an `Integer[]`, with `new Integer`'s if those are `int`'s). This error should only show up in like Java 1.4 (which has been out of date since 2004), since Java 5 introduced autoboxing and the `Object...` parameter to `format`, at which point this error shouldn't happen any more. Although if that's the case, I'd be surprised if `int[]` wouldn't have problems here, given that it's expecting an `Object[]` (i.e. an array of non-primitives). (Not that I've ever used Java 1.4.) Mostly I'd recommend using a newer version of Java.

Comment: It has more todo with the Compiler version than the syntax....changing from 1.4 to 1.7 fixed my issue....the format of the method is the same across multiple languages, an array parameters do not require a parameter value when they are the last parameter in the signature.

Answer (score 5):

I hit this error because the default compiler was set to 1.4.  Setting it to 1.7 resolved it.

In Eclipse: Properties/Java Compiler, click box to Enable project specific settings, use Compiler compliance level 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

Set the default compiler to 1.6 or 1.7
Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: This is the same answer as @drb's two years before you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis.

```
statusbar.setText(String.format("%d, %d", event.getX(), event.getY());
```

Should be:

```
statusbar.setText(String.format("%d, %d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt work :(

Comment: @user3421750 what do you mean by "didnt work"? Is there a new issue?

Comment: yes there is an issue it gives me the same error which is :

Comment: The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int).

Comment: I just checked and the code compiles perfectly fine for me. Try rebuilding the project in your IDE.

Comment: UGH i cant figure this out!!!

Comment: HELP PLEASE I NEED HELP

Comment: ok nvm your were right my "compilance lvl" was too low