# Total of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

what is the java code i need to use to get the tax,  of the following items, when i use

iTotal = string.format("€", itemcost[20]/100];

i get the error:

> The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)

the following is my code;

```
    itemcost[0] = Double.parseDouble(txtApple.getText()) * 30;
    itemcost[1] = Double.parseDouble(txtOrange.getText()) * 20;
    itemcost[2] = Double.parseDouble(txtBrocolli.getText()) * 05;
    itemcost[3] = Double.parseDouble(txtLettuce.getText()) * 05;
        itemcost[4] = Double.parseDouble(txtGrapes.getText()) * 15; itemcost[5] = Double.parseDouble(txtWine.getText()) * 3000;
    itemcost[6] = Double.parseDouble(txtRum.getText()) * 15000;
    itemcost[7] = Double.parseDouble(txtGin.getText()) * 2000;

    itemcost[8] = Double.parseDouble(txtCheese.getText()) * 500;
    itemcost[9] = Double.parseDouble(txtMeatballs.getText()) *420;
    itemcost[10] = Double.parseDouble(txtBacon.getText()) * 300;
    itemcost[11] = Double.parseDouble(txtMeat.getText()) * 400;
    itemcost[12] = Double.parseDouble(txtRice.getText()) * 80;
    itemcost[13] = Double.parseDouble(txtBeans.getText()) * 100;
    itemcost[14] = Double.parseDouble(txtBeanSprouts.getText()) * 100;
    itemcost[15] = Double.parseDouble(txtCucumber.getText()) * 50;

    itemcost[16] = Double.parseDouble(txtCarrots.getText()) * 20;
    itemcost[17] = Double.parseDouble(txtCelery.getText()) * 25;
    itemcost[18] = Double.parseDouble(txtCorriander.getText()) * 20;
    itemcost[19] = Double.parseDouble(txtTomatoes.getText()) * 20;
    itemcost[20] =  itemcost [0] + itemcost[1]+itemcost[2]+ itemcost[3];
    itemcost[21] = itemcost[7] + itemcost[8] + itemcost [9] +
    itemcost[10]  itemcost[22] = itemcost [14] + itemcost[15] +
    itemcost[16]; itemcost[23]= itemcost[17] +itemcost[18] + itemcost
    [19];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The method format(String, Object\[\]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975413/the-method-formatstring-object-in-the-type-string-is-not-applicable-for-the)

Comment: If you're newly learning Java, the first thing I'd recommend doing is moving to a newer version of Java. Also, check [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for the syntax of `format`.

Comment: Please write questions properly. The code you've shown us does not contain the line that causes the error. Also, the line in the main section of your question is different from the line in your actual code; you've written `string.format` instead of `String.format`. Don't type code into your question, but copy & paste your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason is in method `String.format`. You are passing too many arguments in it.

If you want to add the "€", just use the string concatenation.

If you want to format your `double` value, use `String.format("%.2f€", myArg)`, which will return the value of rounded `myArg` with a "€" sign.

[See the examples here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/java-string-format-examples)

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that he's using an old version of Java (pre-1.5) which doesn't understand varargs.